# Reactor: Expand a ParallelFlux

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have a collection of items that needs to be expanded so I chose reactor for its reactive capabilities since the expansion requires IO operations.

Here is a piece of working code:

```java
public Flux<Item> expand(List<Item> unprocessedItems) {
  return Flux.fromIterable(unprocessedItems)
    .expandDeep(this::expandItem);
}
```

Note that `this::expandItem` is a blocking operation (multiple database queries, some computation, ...).
Now I would like this expansion to be parallel but as far as I know `.expand()` and `.expandDeep()` are only members of the `Flux` class and not the `ParallelFlux` class. I tried adding `.publishOn()` and `.subscribeOn()` before the `.expand()` call but without luck.

It's my first time using reactor but I don't see any technical issue preventing a parallel expansion, is there any way to do it? Is the API missing or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

yes you are right `ParallelFlux` has not `.expand()` and `.expandDeep()` methods, 
but I can use other way, create additional Publisher that has expand method and pass it to your `ParallelFlux`, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {      

    Function<Node, Flux<Node>> expander =
        node -> Flux.fromIterable(node.children);

    List<Node> roots = createTestNodes();

    Flux.fromIterable(roots)
        .parallel(4)
        .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
        .flatMap(node -> Flux.just(node).expandDeep(expander))
        .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("Time: " + System.currentTimeMillis() + " thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " value: " + i))
        .sequential()
        .subscribe();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("finished");

}
```

My test data:

```
static final class Node {
    final String name;
    final List<Node> children;

    Node(String name, Node... nodes) {
        this.name = name;
        this.children = new ArrayList<>();
        children.addAll(Arrays.asList(nodes));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

static List<Node> createTestNodes() {
    return new Node("root",
        new Node("1",
            new Node("11")
        ),
        new Node("2",
            new Node("21"),
            new Node("22",
                new Node("221")
            )
        ),
        new Node("3",
            new Node("31"),
            new Node("32",
                new Node("321")
            ),
            new Node("33",
                new Node("331"),
                new Node("332",
                    new Node("3321")
                )
            )
        ),
        new Node("4",
            new Node("41"),
            new Node("42",
                new Node("421")
            ),
            new Node("43",
                new Node("431"),
                new Node("432",
                    new Node("4321")
                )
            ),
            new Node("44",
                new Node("441"),
                new Node("442",
                    new Node("4421")
                ),
                new Node("443",
                    new Node("4431"),
                    new Node("4432")
                )
            )
        )
    ).children;
}
```

And result:

```
Time: 1549296674522 thread: parallel-4 value: 4
Time: 1549296674523 thread: parallel-4 value: 41
Time: 1549296674523 thread: parallel-2 value: 2
Time: 1549296674523 thread: parallel-2 value: 21
Time: 1549296674523 thread: parallel-3 value: 3
Time: 1549296674523 thread: parallel-3 value: 31
Time: 1549296674523 thread: parallel-1 value: 1
Time: 1549296674523 thread: parallel-1 value: 11
Time: 1549296674525 thread: parallel-2 value: 22
Time: 1549296674525 thread: parallel-2 value: 221
Time: 1549296674526 thread: parallel-3 value: 32
Time: 1549296674526 thread: parallel-3 value: 321
Time: 1549296674526 thread: parallel-3 value: 33
Time: 1549296674526 thread: parallel-3 value: 331
Time: 1549296674526 thread: parallel-3 value: 332
Time: 1549296674526 thread: parallel-3 value: 3321
Time: 1549296674526 thread: parallel-4 value: 42
Time: 1549296674526 thread: parallel-4 value: 421
Time: 1549296674526 thread: parallel-4 value: 43
Time: 1549296674526 thread: parallel-4 value: 431
Time: 1549296674526 thread: parallel-4 value: 432
Time: 1549296674526 thread: parallel-4 value: 4321
Time: 1549296674527 thread: parallel-4 value: 44
Time: 1549296674527 thread: parallel-4 value: 441
Time: 1549296674527 thread: parallel-4 value: 442
Time: 1549296674527 thread: parallel-4 value: 4421
Time: 1549296674528 thread: parallel-4 value: 443
Time: 1549296674528 thread: parallel-4 value: 4431
Time: 1549296674528 thread: parallel-4 value: 4432
```

As you can see `expander` worked in parallel threads.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately the `expand` operation is not parallel in your solution. As you can see only the `parallel-4` thread will unfold the fourth `Node`. It can quickly become an issue if `Node` 1 to 3 only unfold a couple of times but the 4th unfolds millions of times.

Comment: I added time to result, if you see 4 threads started at the same time.

Comment: parallel-4 worked longer because Node 4 is greater then first 3

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. If Node 4 unfolds millions of times then only `parallel-4` will work so it becomes sequential.

Comment: I see your point. So You have to write a more complicated code for parallel unfolds.

Answer (score -1):

Here is one example, based on example given by [YauhenBalykin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7185610/yauhen-balykin):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Function<Node, Flux<Node>> expander =
            node -> Flux.fromIterable(node.children)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());

    List<Node> roots = createTestNodes();

    Flux.fromIterable(roots)
            .expand(expander)
            .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("Time: " + System.currentTimeMillis() + " thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " value: " + i))
            .subscribe();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("finished");

}
```

Test data:

```
static final class Node {
    final String name;
    final List<Node> children;

    Node(String name, Node... nodes) {
        this.name = name;
        this.children = new ArrayList<>();
        children.addAll(Arrays.asList(nodes));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

static List<Node> createTestNodes() {
    return new Node("root",
            new Node("1",
                    new Node("11")
            ),
            new Node("2",
                    new Node("21"),
                    new Node("22",
                            new Node("221")
                    )
            ),
            new Node("3",
                    new Node("31"),
                    new Node("32",
                            new Node("321")
                    ),
                    new Node("33",
                            new Node("331"),
                            new Node("332",
                                    new Node("3321")
                            )
                    )
            ),
            new Node("4",
                    new Node("41"),
                    new Node("42",
                            new Node("421")
                    ),
                    new Node("43",
                            new Node("431"),
                            new Node("432",
                                    new Node("4321")
                            )
                    ),
                    new Node("44",
                            new Node("441"),
                            new Node("442",
                                    new Node("4421")
                            ),
                            new Node("443",
                                    new Node("4431"),
                                    new Node("4432")
                            )
                    )
            )
    ).children;
}
```

Result:

```
Time: 1636182895717 thread: main value: 1
Time: 1636182895754 thread: main value: 2
Time: 1636182895754 thread: main value: 3
Time: 1636182895754 thread: main value: 4
Time: 1636182895761 thread: parallel-1 value: 11
Time: 1636182895761 thread: parallel-2 value: 21
Time: 1636182895761 thread: parallel-2 value: 22
Time: 1636182895762 thread: parallel-3 value: 31
Time: 1636182895762 thread: parallel-3 value: 32
Time: 1636182895762 thread: parallel-3 value: 33
Time: 1636182895762 thread: parallel-4 value: 41
Time: 1636182895762 thread: parallel-4 value: 42
Time: 1636182895762 thread: parallel-4 value: 43
Time: 1636182895762 thread: parallel-4 value: 44
Time: 1636182895764 thread: parallel-7 value: 221
Time: 1636182895764 thread: parallel-9 value: 321
Time: 1636182895764 thread: parallel-10 value: 331
Time: 1636182895765 thread: parallel-10 value: 332
Time: 1636182895765 thread: parallel-12 value: 421
Time: 1636182895765 thread: parallel-1 value: 431
Time: 1636182895765 thread: parallel-1 value: 432
Time: 1636182895766 thread: parallel-2 value: 441
Time: 1636182895766 thread: parallel-2 value: 442
Time: 1636182895766 thread: parallel-2 value: 443
Time: 1636182895766 thread: parallel-6 value: 3321
Time: 1636182895767 thread: parallel-9 value: 4321
Time: 1636182895767 thread: parallel-11 value: 4421
Time: 1636182895767 thread: parallel-12 value: 4431
Time: 1636182895767 thread: parallel-12 value: 4432
finished
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30271971)